# Invalid BACKEND error when I have the seemingly correct settings -- why?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Running Django 1.8 on a django development server on Ubuntu 14.04.
I get this error:

```
Invalid BACKEND for a template engine: <not defined>. Check your TEMPLATES setting.
```

My settings file has:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

and when I do `python manage.py diffsettings I get:

```
...
TEMPLATES = [{'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'BACKEND':    'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
 'OPTIONS':{'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 
'django.template.context_processors.request', 
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}},
 {'TEMPLATE_DEBUG': 'DEBUG'}]
```

*And* I can use it when I go to a shell and import it through django.conf. What gives?

Update:

It may be worth noting I'm running python3.

Comment: did you restart the server_

Comment: Good point @levi, but yes with the same results. The TEMPLATES  is included in the variables listed on the debug page.

Comment: That bizarre. Your config is correct. You don't have another one somewhere else in the file? Are you sure your virtualenv is active?

Comment: Do you have an old `settings.pyc` file hanging around anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear. It seemed to be the fact that there was an extra element tagged on the end, the `{TEMPLATE_DEBUG: DEBUG}` element in the list. Removed that and it gets past that point now.

This is actually the old way of doing it. The 1.8 way is to have `debug: True` as a key-word in the dictionary.